# Launch time calculation discrepancies

Tags: ios

It's known that we can use `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` to get the pre main launch times and we can use the instruments profiling as well. However, the two values do not seem to co-relate.

This is what `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` prints

```
Total pre-main time: 350.12 milliseconds (100.0%)
         dylib loading time:  54.76 milliseconds (15.6%)
        rebase/binding time:  15.87 milliseconds (4.5%)
            ObjC setup time:  45.16 milliseconds (12.8%)
           initializer time: 234.23 milliseconds (66.9%)
           slowest intializers :
             libSystem.B.dylib :   7.23 milliseconds (2.0%)
   libBacktraceRecording.dylib :   7.03 milliseconds (2.0%)
    libMainThreadChecker.dylib :  38.22 milliseconds (10.9%)
                        ***SDK :  12.30 milliseconds (3.5%)
                      ******** : 149.65 milliseconds (42.7%)
```

And this is the graph that we can see on instruments.

[image]

As you can see, `Initializing` time seems much greater than the 350ms shown by `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS`. Can someone help make sense of these two?